# View scoped bean is instantiated twice on one page, if there is no redirect when going to page

Tags: jsf, navigation, scope

I have a page where I use @ViewScoped bean. On page I get data from the bean, and call action on it. Something like this:

```
<h:form>
  <h:dataTable value="#{partyBean.foundOrganisations}" var="party">
    <h:column headerClass="header">
      <f:facet name="header">
        #{msgs['company.registration.number']}
      </f:facet>
      <h:commandLink value="#{party.registrationNumber}" action="#{partyBean.select}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{party}" target="#{partyBean.selectedParty}" />
      </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

`partyBean` is `@ViewScoped`. When I get to this page by navigation rule with `<redirect />`, everything works fine, but when there is no `<redirect />`, `foundOrganisations` are taken from one instance of the bean, but `setSelectedParty` is called on another instance of the bean when link is clicked. Checked by debug.

Why is that? Can I do something to make it work without `<redirect />`?

Answer (score 0):

I think its perfectly normal. partyBean is renew with new view. 
For a submit to same page you can change your commandLink with command button and return null in action method. In this way JSF acts like same view.

Or you can try keep selectedparty value in a hiddenField (not tested in JSF 2.0)